# RelayCommand not firing CanExecute

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm trying to create a command that binds to a button, and depends on a hierarchy of viewmodels to represent a pivot and pivotitems in a wp7 app. It goes something like this (i'll omit as much boilerplate code as possible):

Parent viewmodel :

```c#
    public RelayCommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _refreshCommand;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_refreshCommand == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _refreshCommand;
            _refreshCommand = value;

            // Update bindings, no broadcast
            RaisePropertyChanged(RefreshCommandPropertyName);
        }
    }


    public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> LoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            Action<RoutedEventArgs> getCurrentViewmodel = (args) =>
            {
                CurrentViewModel = SearchByLocationViewModel; // maybe something better...
                RefreshCommand = CurrentViewModel.RefreshResultsCommand;
                RefreshCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            };
            return new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(getCurrentViewmodel);
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> PivotItemChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            Action<SelectionChangedEventArgs> pivotChanged = (args) =>
            {
                if (args != null)
                {
                    // update current viewmodel
                    CurrentViewModel = ((Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PivotItem) args.AddedItems[0]).DataContext as ISearchViewModelBase;
                    RefreshCommand = CurrentViewModel.RefreshResultsCommand;
                }
            };
            return new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(pivotChanged);
        }
    }
```

So, i'm setting the parent view model's RefreshCommand property to the child command each time it loads, and I do the same when the selected pivotitem changes.

Xaml

```
<Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
```

Child viewmodel

```c#
public Func<bool> CanRefresh
{
    get { return () => !IsLoading; }
}

private RelayCommand refreshResultsCommand;

public RelayCommand RefreshResultsCommand
{
    get
    {
        Action doRefresh = () =>
        {
            SearchResults.Clear();
            this._pageNumber = 0;
            AddItems();
        };
        return refreshResultsCommand = refreshResultsCommand ?? new RelayCommand(doRefresh, CanRefresh);
    }
}
```

What happens is, the CanRefresh is NEVER called. The commands work fine, depending on the pivotitem it calls one AddItems (that's a virtual method implemented differently in each child viewmodel) or the other, but it's like CanExecute is never raised. I'm using MVVM Light toolkit.
Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'the CanRefresh is NEVER called', do you mean the `CanRefresh` property, or the lambda within it?  How can you tell that it is never called?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `CanExecute` method is never being called because the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the `RelayCommand` is never being fired on a view-model object that the view-layer is currently bound to.  Since you're creating commands on most property accesses, there are a lot of commands about, and it's quite possible that you're firing the event on a command that isn't yet bound to by the view-layer or one that is no longer bound to.

I've never seen anyone create new commands every time the property getter is called.  Could you try creating the commands once in a constructor instead of on every property access instead, and see if that fixes things?

Comment: @DanielPerez: you are indeed calling the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method, sorry for not noticing it.  It was well hidden, though.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are creating a new relay command everytime you call your `LoadedCommand` and `PivotChangedComman` properties. As SL/WPF calls these properties quite frequently you have to ensue that you not create a command everytime the property is called. Actually your `RefreshResultsCommand` implements the correct pattern.

The best way to ensure you implementing the properties/commands properly is to use [Laurent's MVVM snippets](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c93512221fc7#Snippets%2fCSharp). Download them to your snippet directory and just use them. Besides producing always the same boilerplate code and thus improving quality, they also **speed up things considerably!**

You can [use the installer](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/installing/) to install the snippets as well.